# Which day is considered as a trigger day for weekly dataset/pipeline?

Tags: azure-data-factory

If I define my dataset/pipeline as weekly -- which day does ADF consider by default provided I am not adding any offset? For Daily and Monthly it's clear to me -- for Monthly for example it is first day of the month and for daily the first hour of the day. So what is that for weekly? Exactly on which day will it get triggered?

And another question -- if I want the pipeline to execute in middle of week every week (e.g. Thursday every week) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the ISO standard for week which is **Monday**.

For the second part of your question then using the offset attribute will deal with this. For example:

```
"availability": {
    "frequency": "Week",
    "interval": 1,
    "offset": "04.00:00:00",
    "style": "StartOfInterval"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: we have a weekly frequency but its offset is "75.00:00:00". In your example it allowing 2 digits before. If we give "75.00:00:00" like this when the activity will run.